# Trigger different event after changing class - Jquery

Tags: jquery

On my html page, there is a button which initially have the class name "show-update". After clicking on that button, that button will be changed to another class name and i want to set another clicking event to that particular class. However, i am still not successful to do that. Is there anyone know how to fix it ? I am using jquery 1.72

This is my code http://jsfiddle.net/dwGCH/1/

Comment: this worked for me
http://jsfiddle.net/dwGCH/2/

or this with on
http://jsfiddle.net/dwGCH/4/

Comment: What is the problem? You code is working fine, first click pos up a message, second click onwards does nothing, which is expected, as the second class' click event has no function to perform.

Comment: @Breezer your solution makes the second click triggered right after the first click. I prefer the Prowla 's way. Thank you, anyway :)

Comment: oh... well it was you who made the line $(this).off('click');
which triggers the click event... I only fixed your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dwGCH/3/

```
   $('.show-update').click(function() {
      $(this)
      .addClass('update-profile')
      .removeClass("show-update")
      .unbind()
      .click(function() {
         alert('updated'); 
      });
      alert('change to update'); 
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dwGCH/9/

Add a click event first to the temporary class, and then one to the button class which only fires if the updated class is present.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.update-profile', function(){
    alert('updated');
 });

 $(".show-update").on('click', function(e){ 
     // some function here
     // ...           
     $(this).addClass("update-profile").removeClass("show-update").off('click');
     alert('change to update');
 });​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dwGCH/10/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understood, this code toggles two handlers on each click:

```
 $('.update-profile').on('click', function(){
    alert('updated');
 });

$(".show-update").on('click', fn1);

function fn1(event)
{             
     // some function here
     // ...           
     $(this).addClass("update-profile");
     $('.update-profile').removeClass("show-update");
     $(this).off('click');
    $(this).on('click', fn2);
     alert('fn1');
}
function fn2(event)
{             
     // some function here
     // ...           
     $(this).removeClass("update-profile");
     $('.update-profile').addClass("show-update");
     $(this).off('click');
    $(this).on('click', fn1);
     alert('fn2');
}
```